# How to use expression advice or error channel for exception handling?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. I have to handle few exceptions using spring integration.
we are using xml files for spring integration.

```
<int:chain id="sample-chain" input-channel="callTestChannel" output-channel="testResponseChannel">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
            <int:header name="Accept" value="application/json"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int-http:outbound-gateway id="testGateway"
                                   url-expression="headers.externalUrl"
                                   http-method="GET"
                                   expected-response-type="com.example.test.TestProject"
                                   charset="UTF-8"
                                   request-factory="httpComponentClientRequestFactory"
                                   mapped-request-headers="Content-Type,Accept"
                                   reply-timeout="5000">
            <int-http:uri-variable name="testId" expression="payload" />
            <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
                    <property name="recoveryCallback">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                            <constructor-arg ref="retryErrorChannel" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="retryTemplate" ref="retryLoadTemplate" />
                </bean>
            </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
        <int:transformer ref="fetchDetailsTransformer" method="processServiceDetails" />
    </int:chain>

<int:channel id="retryErrorChannel"/>
<int:transformer input-channel="retryErrorChannel" output-channel="markErrorChannel"
                 expression="payload.getFailedMessage()"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="markErrorChannel" output-channel="tmsResponseChannel"
                 expression="'this Id :' + payload + ' could not find.'"/>


<bean id="retryLoadTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="4" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="5" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can someone please help how to create error channel for handling different exceptions? can I use some property on int-http:outbound-gateway?
I have read at some places to use expression advice but did not find any examples about using it in xml files or how to use them at all? or if there is any easy way to handle exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for that advice is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Over here you can find some samples how to configure those advices: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/intermediate/retry-and-more

Comment: thanks for the example. would you know why this #exception.cause.message will give error below: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'cause' cannot be found on null?

Comment: The `#exception` SpEL variable is `null`. Not clear "why?" if you use it only for the `onFailureExpression`

Comment: do you mean I have to set up onFailureExpression ? I am using it as <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
     <property name="successChannel" ref="afterSuccessFetchChannel" />
     <property name="failureChannel" ref="afterFailFetchChannel" />
    </bean>

Comment: <int:transformer input-channel="afterSuccessFetchChannel" output-channel="goodResultChannel"
      expression="'Fetching load id: ' + payload + ' details was successful'" />

 <int:transformer input-channel="afterFailFetchChannel" output-channel="badResultChannel"
      expression="payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message" />

Comment: I mean, I am not setting onFailureExpression in the bean, instead just using expression in transformer!

Comment: If you don't manipulate that `onFailureExpression`, then a `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException` is send to that `afterFailFetchChannel`. And it is definitely true that there is no an `#exception` SpEL variable for that transformer context. You just can do this: `payload.cause.message`.

Comment: sure! 
In this case, can you please explain it conceptually how does it work,
I mean should the exception be thrown in the logs or it just gets sent to the output channel(badResultChannel) as an error?
And also how can I throw some custom exception so that end user will understand what an error is?
Because as of now, I see api just returns this,
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-16T21:24:12.313+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": “/abc/12345678
}

Comment: Yes, you can throw a new exception from that `badResultChannel` flow. You can see how it works in the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/handler/advice/ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java